# Touchpad malfunctioning (Dell laptop)

Tags: touchpad, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 14z laptop.
When I'm moving the moust pointer using touchpad,
it sometimes automatically 'clicks' by itself.
(I have turned on the 'Tap to click' option, but this happens even if I turn that option off)

Then when I really tapped the touchpad, it won't be clicked.
(of course, this is a problem only if I turned the 'tap to click' option on)

I've already checked 'Pointing devices' in the Control Panel and there was no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go Start > Settings > Control Panel.

Open up the Mouse properties.

Click on the touch pad tab. Here you can toggle the tap off when typing.

Now select touch sensitivity and adjust it to low. Apply and click okay.

This should handle the problem. Also make sure to clean off your touch pad if it's dirty - this can contribute to it.

**Edit: if that doesn't handle the problem you can go to**

Start > Settings > Control Panel > Mouse Properties.

Then select device settings and go to settings. Select sensitivity, touch sensitivity and turn on Heavy Touch. Apply and OK.